# _dl_close Assertion failure

Tags: c, apache, debugging, dlopen

I'm using dlopen() in an Apache module that I am writing so that I can have a plugin system for my module. I've found that if I compile my module, compile my plugin, and start Apache, everything works peachy-keen.

If, however, after I have done all that, I recompile my plugin, (making a small change or two to the plugins code,) my next page load will cause Apache to segfault. Each subsequent request works just fine, again. Thus, it is only the first page load immediately after compiling that causes the segfault.

I've been trying to tackle this for a few days (I'm not great at C debugging) and today, I noticed this in my apache error logs:

```
Inconsistency detected by ld.so: dl-close.c: 719: _dl_close: Assertion `map->l_init_called' failed!
```

Anyone have any idea what's going on? Does this mean it's not my code and that I've been hunting a phantom bug? I am fairly confident that I call dlcose() for each call to dlopen(). However, this particular bug/segfault seems to happen when I run apache in single-process mode and start refreshing the page quickly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some ideas:

1. Probably you call `dlopen()` more then once? `dl` library maintains reference counters which is incremented on every `dlopen()` so `dlclose()` will unload the library ONLY if counter == 0.
2. Did you specify `RTLD_NODELETE` flag for `dlopen()` (assuming you are on Linux)? If yes, `dlclose()` won't unload your library.

Did you try to debug syscalls with `strace`? Start Apache, finds its pid and trace all syscalls Apache doesn by calling `strace -p<pid>`. Probably it will give you some idea what is going on.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I am not using RTLD_NODELETE. I am pretty sure I am calling dllcose for every call to dlopen (though at distinctly different points in the code.) I will check one more time.